# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gnupg, apt, apt-key

I am trying to use Ubuntu 20 or Ubuntu 22 in Docker. My `Dockerfile` is:

```
from ubuntu:22.04
run DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt update
```

I build this with `docker build .`. The result is:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/2 : from ubuntu:22.04
---> 2dc39ba059dc
Step 2/2 : run DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt update
---> Running in b15002ae9dd5

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB] 
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security 
InRelease [110 kB] 
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB] 
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB] Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease   
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 871920D1991BC93C
```

I get this message repeated several times, until I get:

```
W: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '_apt' executing apt-key.
```

I have tried to `chmod a+rwx /etc/apt -R` as the first `run` command in the `Dockerfile` but it made no difference.

I have also explicitly run `docker pull ubuntu:22.04` and it said it was already up-to-date. I have the exact same problem with the `ubuntu:20.04` image.

I have consulted all other web sources referring to this problem, but they all require me to be able to run `apt install apt-key` or something else, but I can't update `apt` to start with so nothing works, besides the first 3 pages of search engine hits just showing how to install Docker on Ubuntu and not the other way around.

I have also tried `--security-opt seccomp:unconfined` as mentioned in another answer. That responded with `Error response from daemon: The daemon on this platform does not support setting security options on build`.

So my image doesn't have `curl`, `wget` or `gnupg` and I can't install it without getting this working. When I do anything with `apt-key` I get: `E: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation`

I have managed to install `gnupg` manually from the deb file, and manually receiving the key, which gives a similar error message:

```
# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.rQuYmKpjpo/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 871920D1991BC93C
gpg: requesting key 991BC93C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 991BC93C: public key "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA:  1)
W: The key(s) in the keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg are ignored as the file is not readable by user '' executing apt-key.
```

I have also tried trimming down `/etc/apt/source.list` to the minimum. Same problem.

How can I add the required key from the host?

As a secondary question, how can such a mainstream tool, and distribution, be broken? Has everybody moved on to something else, and what is it? I do not have good internet access so keeping up to date with what is happening in the computer world is a challenge.

Comment: This isn't really a programming or code-related issue, and should instead be on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: How can I move it? This is for programming because it is the foundation on which I need to compile something else and I am not sure if it is a docker or Debian problem?

Comment: Askubuntu also says I have to wait 40 minutes before I can post it, and it also says I don't have enough reputation to add tags. Would you be so kind so as to move it?

Comment: Ever solve this? I can't seem to install docker either on ubuntu `20.04` for the same reasons.

Answer (score 15):

Just upgrade the docker on the host.
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

This is a rare incompatibility of a new syscall to protect keys, that older Docker doesn't support. There is no way to patch Ubuntu to work on old Docker, I spent half a day trying.

Comment: OMG you are a lifesaver - I spent an entire day trying different `gpg` / `apt-key` approaches and this was the answer. Thanks so much!